# How to enable Bigquery API using Service usage?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I know how to enable any service from API, but I want to do same using service usage SDK (Java SDK).

How to enable any service or API using serviceusage SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [this page](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable) you can find the relevant CURL call that you can turn into simple Java code. You can enable up to 20 services using [batchEnable](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/batchEnable).

Example from manual:

> gcurl -d '{ "serviceIds": ["pubsub.googleapis.com",
>   "dataflow.googleapis.com"] }'
>   https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/357084163378/services:batchEnable

Note: You must substitute your project number in the following command.